# ¿Cómo defino recursivamente una resta según restas sucesivas?

Tags: python, funciones, bucle-for

Practicando recursividad, me surge una duda:

```
def sumar(x,y):
    if y==0:
        return 1
    else:
        return x-sumar(x,y-1)
numero1=int(input("Ingrese numero:"))
numero2=int(input("Ingrese otro numero:"))
print(sumar(numero1,numero2))
```

como puedo plantearlo? ya que no lo logro resolver
gracias

Comment: Es resta o suma lo que quieres plantear?

Comment: Lo que quiero plantear es resta

Answer (score 1):

Aquí una forma posible con recursividad.

```
def resta(x, y):
    if y == 0:
        return x
    return resta(x, y-1) - 1
```

De esta forma se genera una concatenación de `y` veces `-1` que se restan del valor `x` al cumplirse la última recursividad dada por `y == 0`.